# Automatically generate process core during CPU spike

Tags: linux, core-dump, cpu-usage

I have a process running on Linux box which occasionally takes more than 100% (its a quad-core processor) CPU (as seen in 'top' output) and the other commands running on this process get stuck. By the time I notice this and dump process core, the CPU utilization drops to normal and the core does not show anything unusual.

Is there any way (command, script, etc.) which can generate process core based on CPU utilization, i.e. during spike automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You could try

`while true; do ps -eo pcpu,pid,user,args | sort -k 1 -r | head -10 >> logfile.txt; echo "\n" >> logfile.txt; sleep 3; done`

This script will show you the top ten processes in terms of CPU usage.